# Find time difference in milliseconds awk or gawk

Tags: awk

I have file with huge data into following format i want to find out the difference between two timestamp in millisecond and add a column at the last with time difference of that row

```sh
22159   | a | 2021-02-26 11:02:03.776 | 2021-02-26 11:02:04.740 <br/>
22160   | b | 2021-02-26 11:35:21.796 | 2021-02-26 11:35:22.674 <br/>
22161   | c | 2021-02-26 11:35:21.806 | 2021-02-26 11:35:22.841 <br/>
22161   | d | 2021-02-26 11:02:18.688 | 2021-02-26 11:02:19.594 <br/>
22182   | e | 2021-02-26 11:06:02.978 | 2021-02-26 11:06:03.815 <br/>
22183   | f | 2021-02-26 11:35:24.911 | 2021-02-26 11:35:25.791 <br/>
22184   | g | 2021-02-26 11:35:25.082 | 2021-02-26 11:35:26.121 <br/>
22199   | h | 2021-02-26 11:09:47.815 | 2021-02-26 11:09:48.499 <br/>
22200   | i | 2021-02-26 11:35:27.562 | 2021-02-26 11:35:28.660 <br/>
22200   | j | 2021-02-26 11:09:49.595 | 2021-02-26 11:09:50.596 <br/>
```

Output eg.

> `9535 a   2021-02-27 11:02:53.756 2021-02-27 11:02:53.947 0.191`

I have tied below command:

```
awk -F'|' 'function convert(t) {   cmd = "date +%s.%3N -d \""t"\" "; cmd|getline timemilli; return timemilli; } { t2=convert($4);t1=convert($3);printf $1"\t"$2"\t"$3"\t"$4"\t%.3f\n",t2-t1 }' filtered_data
```

Its working fine for small file but its giving me error for huge files

Error:

> `awk: cmd. line:1: (FILENAME=filtered_data FNR=516) fatal: cannot open pipe` date +%s.%3N -d "2021-02-27 11:24:05.618" ' (Too many open files)`

Note: my file is around 10 mb and i want to find difference in single shot. not looping over each line.

Is there any other way to do this in single shot?

Comment: The error message seems to indicate multiple open files, but you just have 1 really big file, is that correct?

Comment: yes. i am opening only single file. and seems for some entries its giving wrong difference: 775875 a 2021-02-27 12:01:44.231 2021-02-27 12:01:44.454 0.000

Comment: I think the error message has to do with using many `|` operators without [closing them](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Close-Files-And-Pipes). See @anubhava's answer.

Comment: You obviously have GNU date as you're using GNU-specific options (`-d` and `%N`) so you must have GNU awk available too but GNU awk wouldn't fail when you have too many open output files or pipes, it'd just slow down, so though it's available you aren't calling it. So just calling GNU awk instead of whatever awk you are calling would avoid that error, but then if you have GNU awk there's a much better way to do what you're trying to do and that's by using it's builtin time functions instead of spawning a subshell to call `date` twice per input line.

Comment: Also - using `getline` like that will quietly produce incorrect output that looks valid if `cmd | getline` fails. On  the few rare occasions where calling `getline` is the right approach you should test its success/fail result before using the var it only populates if it succeeds, see http://awk.freeshell.org/AllAboutGetline for details.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may try this `awk`:

```sh
awk -F'|' '
function convert(t,  cmd, timemilli) {
   cmd = "date +%s.%3N -d \""t"\" "
   cmd | getline timemilli
   close (cmd)  # close this cmd to avoid too many open files
   return timemilli
}
{
   t2=convert($4)
   t1=convert($3)
   printf "%s\t%.3f\n", $1"\t"$2"\t"$3"\t"$4, t2-t1
}' filtered_data
```

Answer (score 2):

Using GNU awk since `mktime()` and `gensub()`:

```
$ gawk '
BEGIN {
    FS=" [|] "
}
function s(dt) {             # function to deal with dt conversion
    return sprintf("%.3f\n", mktime(gensub(/[- :.]/," ","g",dt))+gensub(/^[^.]+/,"","g",dt))
}
{
    $1=$1                    # rebuild the record for requested output
    print $0,s($3)-s($4)     # output
}' file
```

Output:

```
22159 a 2021-02-26 11:02:03.776 2021-02-26 11:02:04.740 -0.964
22160 b 2021-02-26 11:35:21.796 2021-02-26 11:35:22.674 -0.878
22161 c 2021-02-26 11:35:21.806 2021-02-26 11:35:22.841 -1.035
...
```

Notice: `mktime()` requires time in form `"YYYY MM DD HH MM SS [DST]"`. Above I'm abusing (due to laziness) and feeding it form `"YYYY MM DD HH MM SS sss"` where `sss` is the milliseconds. It seems to work but you may want to fix that with for example `substr()` or similar.

Answer (score 1):

For `mawk` 1.3.4. See mawk documentation on `mktime` for the value of
daylight savings time `dst`.

```
LC_ALL=C awk -v FS=' +\| ' -v OFS='|' -v RS=' <br/>\n' -v OFMT='%.3f' -v dst='-1' '
function fn(s) {
    # return epoch seconds, with milliseconds as fraction
    gsub(/-|:/," ",s)
    return mktime(substr(s,1,19) " " dst) + substr(s,21,3)/1000
}{ $(NF+1) = fn($4) - fn($3) }
1
' data
```

**EDIT**  Edited `FS` and `RS` to match OP's new input format.

Comment: with respect to `RS=' <br/>\n'` - I suspect those `<br/>`s aren't actually present in the OPs data but were an attempt at getting the data to appear one row per line in the question by adding HTML breaks before it was formatted properly with markdown.

Comment: @EdMorton: No `<br/>` was present in the sample data of the original posting so I had to assume they're there now. If not the `RS` define can be removed from my code.